# Jetty - Configure Jetty to log only errors

Tags: logging, solr, log4j, jetty, slf4j

How to configure `Jetty 9` to log only critical errors? Because when I'm deploying `Solr` to `Jetty`, `Solr` log files are becoming more & more large.

P.S:
I know that `$JETTY_HOME/etc/jetty-logging.xml` is used to configure logging, and logging frameworks in `Java` are organized in hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the file to edit to log only `warning` errors and above, in `$JETTY_HOME/resources/jetty-logging.properties` put :

`org.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL=WARN`

When deploying an app that require `Log4j` like `Solr`, you need to modify the other file too (`log4j.properties`) :

`log4j.rootLogger=WARN, stdout`